# Object doesn't support property or method initList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, windows-7

I'm getting this error in IE 11, windows 7 environment where I have used jquery 1.7.1
I have read all the answers in stackoverflow related to this and couldn't find solution.  And I have added the below meta tag too.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But surprising that this meta tag is not visible when I do inspect element.

Could you please help me to guess the issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Need to see some code to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Have you add this `<meta>` at the first line of your `<head>` ? It's important

Comment: Where's `initList` defined?  It's not part of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invisibility of meta tag is the my code issue. And It is fixed after I made IE9 compatibility when our application opens in IE browser. i.e changed content="IE=9" in meta tag as following.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```